# How fix this light problem in my real time smoke system?

Tags: lighting

In short, When i rotate the camera, and the camera see the smoke back then the all plane is black. How can i fix it? (The sun rotating is not option!)

Video: https://youtu.be/AlK4pfC9NzU

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots so we don’t have to download the file? Some of us are working on mobile at the moment, so you may get help quicker that way. (This sounds really condescending, but I don’t mean it to be)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.